# Whonix Workstation signature verification fails

Tags: debian, whonix

I'm following the instructions in [this guide](https://anonguide.cyberguerrilla.org/anonguide.pdf) to install Debian on a USB device. I've done every step on pages 129-137, and things went smoothly until I tried to verify the Whonix Workstation file using the command on page 137:

```
$ gpg --verify-options show-notations --verify Whonix-Workstation-*.ova.asc Whonix-Workstation-*.ova
Signature made Mon 19 Jan 2015 22:46:14 GMT using RSA key ID 77BB3C48 // BAD signature from "Patrick Schleizer < adrelanos@riseup.net>
```

I've tried redownloaidng `Whonix-Workstation-9.6.ova.asc` several times, but the verification keeps failing. I think I might have to delete the whole `.ova` file and download it again, but I've never used Linux and I'm pretty lost. Could something else be the problem, or do I need to redownload the `.ova` file?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Okay, I managed to delete the `.ova` file and download it again. Now I can verify properly. Sorry for posting without trying everything before and thank you Michael Mrozek for making my post more understandable.